# Querying from a collection of type ObservableCollection<Dictionary<string, object>>

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Collection of type `ObservableCollection<Dictionary<string, object>>` and one of its properties is 'Group'. How do I write a linq to query all items where "Group == 'SomeGroup'"? I want a list that I can bind to a silverlight grid.

Comment: Are you saying one of the properties of the "object" defined in the dictionary is "Group"?  Are they always the same type of objecT?

Comment: You can read this documentation : [101 Linq Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746.aspx)

Comment: Yes. Its a dynamic class but here in this case it will always have a property by name Group and will remain as the same type. To query this particular property, I could do this myobj.AsEnumerable().Select(row => row["Group"].ToString()) but not sure how to return a collection for a certain condition

Answer (score 0):

Could you may be post some of the code that you used? 
Without it this is what comes to mind:

```
var a = (from m in collection
               from b in m.Values
               where b.Group == "Some Group"
               select b).ToList();
```

Hope it helps